# C Structure Error: Dereferencing pointer to an incomplete type

Tags: c, data-structures, structure

Did i do mistake in declaring the structure? I tried checking several other similar questions based on this error, still wasn't able to find the solution. Need your help to solve it.Thanks In Advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node{
int info;
struct node *link;
} ;

void display(struct node *start);

int main()
{
struct node *start=NULL;

int choice;
int num;

while(1)
{
printf("\n1. Display \n9. Exit \n");

printf("\nEnter your choice\n\n\n");
scanf("%d",&choice);

switch(choice)
{
case 1:
    display(start);
    break;

default:
    printf("\nInvalid choice");

}
}
}
void display(struct node *start)
{
   struct node *p;

    if(start==NULL)
    {
        printf("List Is Empty");
        return;
    }
    p=start;
    while(p!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d",p->info); // Getting Error in these 2 Lines
        p=p->link;            // Getting Error in these 2 Lines
    }

}
```

Comment: `struct Node` is not the same thing as `struct node`.

Comment: @aschelper Thanks, i didn't know that, .It  worked. Thanks for help. Cud you explain the difference between them?

Comment: The difference is the capital N :). Just kidding. *C* is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare pointers to `struct node` but that type is not defined. C is case sensitive.

The reason you get the error where you do is that it isn't until you try to dereference a pointer to the struct the compiler actually needs to know the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a character case issue: you have `struct Node`, but then  `struct node *`, which can't be anything complete, not being at all.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this Struct node* and struct Node*:

there is nothing defined in your code as struct node because first you used struct Node

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    struct node  ///<<< fix 
    {
    int info;
    struct node *link;
} ;

void display(struct node *start);

int main()
{
    struct node *start=NULL;

    int choice;
    int num;

    while(1)
    {
        printf("\n1. Display \n9. Exit \n");

        printf("\nEnter your choice\n\n\n");
        scanf("%d",&choice);

        switch(choice)
        {
        case 1:
            display(start);
            break;

        default:
            printf("\nInvalid choice");

        }
    }
    }
    void display(struct node *start)
    {
    struct node *p;

    if(start==NULL)
    {
        printf("List Is Empty");
        return;
    }
    p=start;
    while(p!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d",p->info); // Getting Error in these 2 Lines

    /// struct node and struct Node are diffrent things

        p=p->link;            // Getting Error in these 2 Lines
    }

}
```